# Using if condition to compare in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get the .Net version from the system and trying to check does my system have .Net version greater than or equal to 4.6 or not. Below is the code. From the code I am able to retrieve the release version. I am facing a problem in the if condition.

```
$myArray = @()

$myArray = @(Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
    Get-ItemProperty -Name Release,Release -EA 0 |
    Where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}' } |
    Select Release)
Write-Output $myArray[0]
Write-Output $myArray[1]

$var1 = 393295
foreach ($var in $myArray) {
    Write-Output $var
    if ($var -ge $var1) {
        Write-Output same
    } else {
        Write-Output NOT same
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot compare "@{Release=461808}" to "393295" because the objects are not the
same type or the object "@{Release=461808}" does not implement "IComparable".
At C:\Users\Desktop\DotNet.ps1:13 char:9
+     if ($var -ge $var1) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSObjectCompareTo
```

Comment: `Select Release` -> `Select -ExpandProperty Release)` you are comparing a object with a release property as supposed to just a string. note that `$var` could be a string so type it with `[int]` to make sure your math is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `foreach` line as

```
foreach($var in $myArray.Release)
```